# Android Studio keeps importing import sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.IntArray

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Every time I copy a piece of code in **Java** and paste it in my android studio, and it converts this code to **Kotlin** code, it keeps automatically importing this:

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.IntArray
```

And every time android studio makes this import, it gives an error `Unresolved reference: sun`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?...it is very annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way I found, and it works so far, is disabling automatic import for specifically `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` packages. Just disabling `sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.IntArray` caused Android Studio to select some other `sun`/`com.sun` packages to imports. Still not sure why, but here is where you can find the setting:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Try adding tools.jar from the jdk to your dependencies.

```
compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
```

Comment: Didn't solve the issue for me.  I manually remove this import every time it gets added/auto-imports.  Seems it's not needed and is just an artifact of auto-converting Java to Kotlin on copy/paste.  Would be preferable to simple not auto-import it.  Haven't found a way to make it not do this yet though. I'm on Android Studio 3.5.3.

Answer (score -3):

To Disable Auto Imports:

> File --> Settings ---> Editor --> General --> Auto Import --> Optimize imports on
>   the fly.

If **Optimize imports on the fly** is checked then uncheck it.

Comment: NO!, i do not want to disable ALL auto imports, maybe just the disturbing one (if even possible)....also i DO NOT WANT to dissable optimize imports on the fly....that does not sound as a good solution so solve the issue.

Comment: You can exclude it instead using the **Exclude from import and completion**

Answer (score -3):

Check your prefrences to copy past smart key.

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Scroll to the end -> Convert posted Java code to Kotlin

turn that off.

Comment: dont thin this is the solution since i DO WANT to convert java to kotlin on copy paste...but avoiding the annoying import mentioned above